# how to find the cursor position in text service frame work in windows8?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, text-services-framework

I am implemented sample IME in this service using Notepad and I want to insert text at the cursor's position in the text. How can I get the cursor's position in windows 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ItfInsertAtSelection::InsertTextAtSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms628599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inserts text at the selection.  Since Notepad isn't TSF-aware, that's the *only* place you can insert text.